# According to a defined array filling in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python. I have dictionary called data_dict which contains many values to single given key. Two of those value are salary and exercised_stock_options.
I want to update these two value in the dictionary for every key. The corresponding salary and stock values for each key are in lists salary_rescale, and stock_rescale respectively.

Here's what I have done till now.

```
salary_rescale=[]
stock_rescale=[]
```

for key in data_dict:

```
  for value in data_dict[key]:
      if (value=="salary"):
          salary_rescale.append(data_dict[key][value])
      if (value=="exercised_stock_options"):
          stock_rescale.append(data_dict[key][value])

feature_scaling(salary_rescale)
feature_scaling(stock_rescale)
```

I want to re enter these two lists back into the dictionary. How will i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
for key in data_dict:
    data_dict[key]['salary_rescaled'] = salary_rescaled
    data_dict[key]['stock_rescaled'] = stock_rescaled
```

I hope I have answered the question, or else you can post comments

Comment: But i want to update the salary and the exercised_stock_option field only. I dont want to add a new one. That's the issue! I can do this but if there is a way kindly tell me

Comment: You want to replace the data[key]['salary'] by salary rescaled ?